# Select value where id in angularjs template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've got two scope objects

```
$scope.selectedItems = [1,3]
$scope.items = [{'id':'1','name':'apple'},{'id':'2','name':'banana'},{'id':'3','name':'grapes'}]
```

In my template I want to use ng-repeat for $scope.selectedItems, but show item names. Is it possible?

Smth. like

```
<span ng-repeat="selItem in selectedItems track by $index">{{ items.name | items.id == selItem }}</span>
```

Comment: you should use same type for `selectedItems` and `items id`. (string or int)

Answer (score 1):

You have few of issues, First is that your ids are string but your stored array of selected items are numbers. My solution tries to accommodate that.

You need to create a third scope property that dynamically calculates the items that have the same id as your selected items ids and returns them.

```
$scope.selectedItemIds = [1,3]
$scope.items = [{'id':'1','name':'apple'},{'id':'2','name':'banana'},{'id':'3','name':'grapes'}];

$scope.selectedItems = function(){

    var _selectedItems = [];

    angular.forEach($scope.items, function(item){
        if ($scope.selectedItemIds.indexOf(Number(item.id)) != -1){
            _selectedItems.push(item);
        }
    });

    return _selectedItems;
};
```

Now you can use that function in your ng-repeat iterator to access the selected items on the view:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in selectedItems()">{{ item.name }}</li>
</ul>
```

[Here is a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/19046/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try it by custom filter:

In controller:

```
$scope.selectedItems = ['1','3'];
$scope.items = [{'id':'1','name':'apple'},{'id':'2','name':'banana'},  {'id':'3','name':'grapes'}];
$scope.getselectedItem= function(item) {
    if($scope.selectedItems.indexOf(item.id)!==-1) {
      return item;
    }
    else {
      return null;
    }
};
```

In Html:

```
<p ng-repeat="item in items | filter: getselectedItem">{{item.name}}</p>
```